# What's the Difference between Template.Instance() vs template.data?

Tags: meteor

When creating a Meteor event handler, what's the difference between...

```
'click .something': function(e,t){
    var data = t.data
}
```

vs

```
'click .something': function(e,t){
    var data = Template.instance().data
}
```

They both seem to bring up the same data. Is there a reason why I should one or the other?

Comment: `Template.instance` is (at the moment) only useful in helpers. In other places (like the `created` callback, the `rendered` callback, etc.) you can get the template instance in other ways, but in these cases you can just as well use `Template.instance` if you prefer.

Comment: note as I wrote in my answer below that while you can access Template.instance().data this way, you should NOT put your own data on this context, or it risks disappearing on next Template render.

Answer (score 8):

Similar question here:

[Difference between Template.instance() and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534580/difference-between-template-instance-and-this)

The thing to realize is that:

In the template life-cycle functions (onCreated, onRendered...) `this` is equal to `Template.instance()` so `this.data` is the same as `Template.instance().data` AT THAT TIME!

In a helper or event, `this` is the current **data context**.

So, note an important thing here: **the Data context can change over time if your data changes upstream:**

If you pass data to a template, the template will be re-rendered with the new data. New data = new data context.

So if you do something like:

```
Template.example.onCreated(function() {
   this.data.myKey = "my example data set on template creation"; //WRONG!
   // or equivalently:
   Template.instance().data.myOtherKey = "another key"; //WRONG!
})
```

well, this data may be under `this` (i.e. the data context) in your helper (`this.myKey`) but only as long as the upstream data does not change.

As soon as the upstream data changes, `this` will be the new data context, and will NOT contain your added data.

So, in summary:

If you need to add context to your template in `onCreated` or `onRendered`, make sure you do NOT bind it to the current data context, but to the Template.instance()

you should do:

```
Template.example.onCreated(function() {
   this.myKey = "my example data set on template creation"; 
   // or equivalently:
   Template.instance().myOtherKey = "another key"; 
})
```

and you can access this data in helper and events via

`Template.instance().myKey`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `Template.instance()` (with a lower i), and as this function returns the current template instance in scope (the one where the event originated), there's no difference with the second parameter of an event handler, which also holds the current template instance, this is why you can access the template data indifferently using `Template.instance().data` or `t.data` in an event handler.

There is however a simpler way to access the current data context inside an event handler : the `this` object is bound to the data context where the event was triggered.