# Difference between Template.instance() and this

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between Template.instance() and this? Is there an advantage to use one or the other?

```
Template.name.onRendered( function() {
 var template = Template.instance(); 
 var instance = this;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

When inside a lifecycle event such as `onCreated`, `onRendered` or `onDestroyed`, `Template.instance()` will return the same object as `this` because in these callback registration functions, `this` is explicitly set to the current template instance by Meteor.

HTML

```
<template name="component">
  <div class="component">
    <p>Hello <em>{{name}}</em>, click the button!</p>
    <button type="button">Click me!</button>
    <p>You clicked <strong>{{count}}</strong> time(s) on the button.</p>
  </div>
</template>

<body>
  {{> component name="World"}}
</body>
```

JS

```
Template.component.onCreated(function(){
  console.log(this == Template.instance());
  // use this to access the template instance
  this.count = new ReactiveVar(0);
  // use this.data to access the data context
  console.log(this.data.name == "World");
});
```

However in template helpers, `this` is bound to the data context of the template, not the template instance itself, so using `Template.instance()` is necessary to access the template instance executing the helper.

```
Template.component.helpers({
  count: function(){
    // use this to access the data context
    console.log(this.name);
    // use Template.instance() to access the template instance
    return Template.instance().count.get();
  }
});
```

Finally, in template events, `this` is also bound to the data context of the template, but the event handler is called with an additional `template` parameter that you may use as a shorthand to `Template.instance()`.

```
Template.component.events({
  "click button": function(event, template){
    // use this to access the data context
    console.log(this.name);
    // use the argument to access the template instance
    var currentCount = template.count.get();
    template.count.set(currentCount + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: in my experience, I observed that the 'data' context gets cleared / regenerated on changes upstream, so anything attached to `this.data` or `Template.instance().data` in `onCreated` etc... gets cleared on the next render.