# Push data between two meteor templates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

I have a simple meteor app with a body template that has a simple form to create a post with `title`, `text`, and `_id`. When I create a post, it renders in the post template which includes an update button. On the javascript side (client), I have a method like so:

```
'click .update'(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;
    post = Post.find({_id: this._id}).fetch();
    //send post's data to the body template so it can be rendered and updated by the user
}
```

Basically I want something with which I can access the body template's instance and set it's `title`, `text`, and `_id` values. I've tried `Template.instance()`, but that doesn't seem to include these variables.

How would I go about doing this? The user should be able to click update, and then edit the info in the same form they use to create posts (I'm using upsert to update instead of create posts when they already exist).

html file with templates:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Post List</h1>
      <form class="new-post">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" />
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Post Body" />
        <input hidden name="_id" />
        <button value="Create">Create</button>
      </form>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each posts}}
        {{> post}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="post">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>{{_id}}</li>
      <li>{{title}}</li>
      <li>{{text}}</li>
      <li><button class="update" value="Update {{id}}" id='{{id}}'>Update</button></li>
      <li><button class="delete" value="Delete {{id}}" id='{{id}}'>Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

logic for update function:

```
Template.body.events({

 'click .update'(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("post id number: " + this._id);
   const target =Template.instance();//I need to get the instance of the body template here (where posts are created)
   posts = Posts.find({_id: this._id}).fetch();
   target.title.value=posts[0].title;
   target.text.value=posts[0].text;
   target._id.value=posts[0]._id;

 }
});
```

obviously there are other functions too...

Comment: You'd want to use the event's template parameter instead of Template.instance(). Check out this post for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35657873/1689286.

Comment: yea, that's great for accessing THAT template's params, but I need to access another template's params. The template is defined as a totally different block of html.

Comment: Are these templates located in the same file or different? Can you post your templates (the pertinent parts)?

Answer (score 1):

First set up a reactiveVar ([please read the reactiveVar docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html)) to hold the form data when you click update.

(Also, move the body `click .update` event to post events )

```
const post = new ReactiveVar({}); // Set it at the top of your js.

Template.body.events({

});

Template.post.events({
  'click .update'(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    post = Posts.find({_id: this._id}).fetch();
    post.set(post);
  }
});
```

Now every time you click a post update button, you will be putting the data from that post into the `post` reactiveVar.

Next, put the post form inside of another template called `postForm`:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Post List</h1>
      {{> postForm}}
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each posts}}
        {{> post}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="postForm">
  {{#with post}}
    <form class="new-post">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" value="{{title}}">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Post Body" value="{{text}}">
      <input hidden name="_id" value="{{_id}}">
      <button value="Create">Save</button>
    </form>
  {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="post">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>{{_id}}</li>
      <li>{{title}}</li>
      <li>{{text}}</li>
      <li><button class="update" value="Update {{id}}" id='{{id}}'>Update</button></li>
      <li><button class="delete" value="Delete {{id}}" id='{{id}}'>Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

Notice the use of `{{#with post}}`. In this example `post` is just a helper that will need to be created to allow access of the `post` reactiveVar inside of your template. Also, note the use of handlebars in each of the input values.

```
Template.postForm.helpers({
    post: function(){
        return post.get();
    }
});
```